# Angular 2 Interpolation with view container and templateRef

Tags: angular

I am trying to mimic ngfor for a paging directive.  Any interpolated value does not display.  In my directive I have :

```
Input() set pageOf(a){
    for(let x of a) {
        this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    }
}
```

In my html I have :

```
<table>
    <tr *page="let a of test" >
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>{{a}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

"abc" displays fine for each element in test but what {{a}} interpolates to does not display.  My guess is somehow I need to tell the view container what a is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found my own answer...in case any one is looking.

```
@Input() set pageOf(a){
    for(let x of a) {
        const view = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        view.context.$implicit = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: For any one else: `createEmbeddedView` takes context as a second parameter